# How to configure autocomplete settings of Kotlin in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Each time when I type `'['` Android Studio finalizing this action by `']'`. It is very annoying, especially in writing KDoc. I tried to find these settings in `AndroidStudio -> Code Style` window, but it seems to be in different place or even doesn't exist.

Do you have an idea, how to disable this annoying autocompletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable there autocomplitions with `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys` and uncheck all `Insert pair...` options.

Comment: long live Axel P! Thank you mate!